# How to create table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm new on Laravel and I read [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/laravel/index.htm)
He explain there how to execute queries on the db such `SELECT` etc...
But he dosent explain how to create tables with Laravel

So can you expalain me how to create tables with Laravel ?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/migrations

Comment: Laravel's documentation is very helpful. Check out their migration section: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/migrations

Answer (score 0):

Laravel Query Builder is also use full. you can find all related to query bulder [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries).